# Duplicate class org.hamcrest.BaseDescription found in the following modules，How to resolve？

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, hamcrest

Duplicate class org.hamcrest.BaseDescription found in the following modules: hamcrest-all-1.3.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3), hamcrest-core-1.3.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3) and mockito-all-2.0.2-beta.jar (org.mockito:mockito-all:2.0.2-beta)

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-all:2.0.2-beta'
androidTestImplementation "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3"
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.1.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
```

Comment: did you already check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55909804/duplicate-class-android-support-v4-app-inotificationsidechannel-found-in-modules or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56402573/duplicate-class-android-support-v4-app-notificationcompatactionextender-found ?