# Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules classes?

Tags: gradle, chat, androidx

I am developing a news app but I am getting following errors in from gradle console

```
(androidx.core:core:1.0.1) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.IconCompatParcelizer found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub$Proxy found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$1 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyRunnable found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.core.graphics.drawable.IconCompatParcelizer found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.core.internal.package-info found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.CustomVersionedParcelable found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.NonParcelField found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.ParcelField found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.ParcelImpl found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.ParcelImpl$1 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.ParcelUtils found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcel found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcel$1 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcel$ParcelException found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcelParcel found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcelStream found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcelStream$FieldBuffer found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcelStream$InputBuffer found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcelable found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcelize found in modules class
```

below my app.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.bassaer:chatmessageview:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'. Ionic4 Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56716047/execution-failed-for-task-appcheckdebugduplicateclasses-ionic4-android)

Comment: Your project (or one of its sub-projects) is referring to a dependency using the **+** plus-sign at its end; check the answer for [Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56736684/8740349) (although that question is about Ionic the answer should work).

Answer (score 535):

You can add below 2 lines into your `gradle.properties` file:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

> **Note** to check, to not repeat any line that already exists (and ensure existing are `true`).

---

#### Details:

Your project (or one of its sub-projects, or a dependency) is no longer using `android.support` libraries and instead is using `androidx` libraries, which causes conflicts if mixed with `android.support` libraries.

If you want to use `androidx`-namespaced libraries in an old project, you need to set the compile SDK to Android 9.0 (API level 28) or higher but below "API level 31", and set both of the mentioned Android Gradle plugin flags to `true`.

**`android.useAndroidX`**: When this flag is set to `true`, the Android plugin uses the appropriate AndroidX library instead of a Support Library. The flag is `false` by default if it is not specified.

**`android.enableJetifier`**: When this flag is set to `true`, the Android plugin automatically migrates existing third-party libraries to use AndroidX dependencies by rewriting their binaries. The flag is `false` by default if it is not specified.

Comment: Can you add a little more information about what exactly this is doing?

Comment: @NathanF. this is because of mixing support libraries. by adding these lines androidX selected as your support library

Comment: This will just forcibly replace any dependency on `android.support.*` with `androidx.*` dependencies (but for me, it just resulted in a compile error because `android.support` was used in the codes), in case anyone is seeking a fix instead of a workaround check the answer for [Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56736684/8740349) (although that question is about Ionic the answer should work).

Comment: same error for me. and I am not using androidX Library but by default is added while compiling. please help me.

Comment: thank you so much. I've been battling a monster series of version errors for hours and this seems to be the last of them. I explicitly had `android.enableJetifier=false` for some reason.

Comment: Adding these lines in my project, generated new errors. For example, "package android.support.annotation does not exist", "cannot find symbol class Fragment", "package android.support.v4.content does not exist", etc.

Comment: @PabloAlfonso if enable jetifier support does not work for you and you should use androidX version of this object such as fragment, etc.

Comment: @nicej I was able to solve the issue by selecting Refactor > "Migrate to AndroidX" from the menu bar. Thanks.

Comment: if no have gradle.properties u must create in root

Comment: not fix, I stay on LinearLayout and didn't use ConstraintLayout ;(

Comment: @Fortran It doesn't matter to constraint layout.

Comment: @AniceJahanjoo yeah), but didn't find "constraint layout" without androidX in my case

Comment: @Fortran yes you exactly right but this problem is related to the whole androidX not just a component like constraint layout.

Comment: yeah I know))))

Comment: Perhaps this resolution shouldn't be your first choice guys, it tends to slow down project builds, as stated in the docs:

"Caution: As of late 2021, most of the library ecosystem already supports AndroidX natively. This means that your project is most likely already using AndroidX libraries directly and there is no need to follow the steps in this migration guide. Additionally, the enableJetifier flag mentioned in this guide can lead to slower build times and should not be used unless it’s necessary."

Comment: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Comment: Instead you should try to use gradle ResolutionStrategy API to solve this problem: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#custom_dep_resolutions

Answer (score 39):

Adding these lines to gradle.properties file solves "Duplicate Class" errors:

```
android.useAndroidX=true

android.enableJetifier=true
```

However, this generated new errors in my project:

"package android.support.annotation does not exist"

"cannot find symbol class Fragment"

"package android.support.v4.content does not exist"

"Program type already present"

etc.

However, the refactoring worked for me:

```
Migrate your project to AndroidX by selecting Refactor > 
"Migrate to AndroidX" from the menu bar.

Select Build > Clean project

Restore Android Studio
```

Now, my project (Match4app) works with AndroidX and I was able to publish it in the PlayStore without any issues.

Comment: This task also allowed me to upgrade all other libraries that depend on AndroidX (i.e. com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.0.2, com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:18.0.1, com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0, com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.2.0, etc.).

Answer (score 15):

> ###### <sup>I run into something like this, and based on my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56736684/8740349):</sup>

Your project (or one of its sub-projects) is referring to a dependency using a **+** (plus-sign) at its end, like `com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:+`, which means, use any higher version when possible, and that newer version is no longer using `android.support` libraries and instead is using `androidx`; to fix this issue, either follow the below steps, or, update to `androidx` by following [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56716047/execution-failed-for-task-appcheckdebugduplicateclasses-ionic4-android#68443034).

### Steps:

1. Ensure the `ANDROID_HOME` environment-variable is set, and then, open a console app (but for Windows, use git-bash), and `cd` into your `android` directory (for Ionic projects it should be `platforms/android`).
2. First, **List all dependencies** into a file, by running below (in said console):

   ```
   ./gradlew :app:dependencies > my-list.txt
   ```

   > **Note** to change `:app` part with another Gradle module's name, if above does not work.
   >
   > See list of said module names, like:
   >
   > ```
   > ./gradlew -q projects
   > ```
3. Open the resulting `my-list.txt` file into your preferred text-editor, and search for `androidx`.
4. If you found something follow below steps, else you are done! (and you do not need to repeat these steps).
5. Scroll up until you see **->** at the end of any line, like for example **`16.0.8 -> 19.0.0`** or **`+ -> 19.0.0`**, which both mean that the version was auto-resolved (to something higher than specified by you because of **+**).
6. Hence, set the version down manually:

   - When possible, in your project find and replace the **+** sign with a specific version.
   - Or, force a specific version of the dependencies like mentioned below.
7. At last, repeat above steps (but just skip step one, unless you closed said console).

---

To **Force specific version of the dependencies** add to your root `build.gradle` file something like below
(which is what worked for me), but of course edit below and add your own rules (because these might not work for your case):

```
allprojects {
  // ...
  configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
      force 'com.google.firebase:firebase-common:17.0.0'
      force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.2.0'
      force 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:16.0.0'
      force 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

**I was having this same issue and this is how i resolved it**

Expand Graddle Scripts and then Go to graddle.properties and add these 2 lines

Note: *Maybe the first line android.useAndroidX=true is already there so do not repeat it.*

android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true

Answer (score 11):

Just add these 2 lines in ***gradle.properties*** file,

```
android.useAndroidX=true

android.enableJetifier=true
```

Now your project will not have any duplicate class error and will work fine,

Thank you

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue.

android.enableJetifier=true

just paste this line in the gradleproperties file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 9):

[image: Solved]
Just set your Gradle properties this way

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Taken from [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx). AndroidX is the open-source project that the Android team uses to develop, test, package, version and release libraries within Jetpack.

Answer (score 4):

Here in 2024, incase you are working on legacy project that depends on com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0 or its associated libraries do this below.

Go to your gradle.properties file and add this code

android.useAndroidX=true

android.enableJetifier=true

Note: android.useAndroidX=true might already exist so avoid repetition

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

Like @Ahmed says, the solution is to implement AndroidX, it works for me. However, it isn´t an easy way and it requires a bit of pacience... These are the steps that I did:

- First, is **very important** that you do all this changes in a different branch or you make a backup of your project.
- You need to have the Android Gradle Plugin Version 3.5.1. So, in *build.gradle* set: `dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
  ...`
- Migrate to AndroidX using Android Studio Tool : *Refactor --> Migrate to AndroidX...*
- When it finishes, it has done all pertinents modification, but posibly you can´t deploy the project correctly because you find any errors. These are the problems that I found and the solutions:
- If you use *Kotlin*, in build.gradle set: `buildscript {
  ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.10'
  ...`
  and `compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"`
- If you use *destination* method, add "file" parameter: `destination file("$reportsDir/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml")`
- If you use *Butterknife*, use 10.0.0 version

Answer (score 3):

I was having this same issue and this is how i resolved it

```
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Answer (score 3):

Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules classes?

android.enableJetifier=true

add this on gradle properties

Answer (score 1):

Modify the module-level build.gradle file to enable multidex and add the multidex library as a dependency

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 15 
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Top-Master's answer only work if you can downgrade to a specific version. In my case, I have a React Native app and one of the libraries I was using had migrated to AndroidX. The previous version had issues with iOS, so I had to use the most recent version. What I had to do was:

1. Migrate the Android project to AndroidX (Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX).
2. Use [jetify](https://github.com/mikehardy/jetifier) to convert `node_module` dependencies to AndroidX. For React Native 0.60 and above, jetify is run automatically, so you don't have to install this library.

Answer (score 0):

android.nonTransitiveRClass=true

add this on gradle properties

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you use admob and faced with duplicate class error like this in Unity. Firstly, Assets -> External Dependecy Manager -> Android Resolver -> Delete Resoved Libraries. After that, Assets -> External Dependecy Manager -> Android Resolver -> Settings -> Enable Resolution On Build. It works for me.