# Having issues with setting up LeakCanary

Tags: leakcanary

LeakCanary setup issues

I am trying to setup via https://github.com/square/leakcanary.

in gradle, I updated
    debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.0-alpha-2'

but getting error 
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.IconCompatParcelizer found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)

Per stackoverflow
[Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55909804/duplicate-class-android-support-v4-app-inotificationsidechannel-found-in-modules)

updated gradle.properties but now getting a error where nothing related to Android is compiling

org.gradle.execution.MultipleBuildFailures: Build completed with 1 failures.
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ExecuteTasks.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:386)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:301)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:293)
    at

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue that was fixed in the beta release, you should update.