# Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses', Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, gradle, firebase-mlkit

How to rectify this error?

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM T385 in debug mode...
 lib\main.dart
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_ml_vision-0.9.9\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebasemlvision\FirebaseMlVisionPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.

 1 exception was raised by workers:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zze found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0) and classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzf found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0) and classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzg found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0) and classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzh found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0) and classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzi found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0) and classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzv found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0) and classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzw found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0) and classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0)

  Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 14s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'. Ionic4 Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56716047/execution-failed-for-task-appcheckdebugduplicateclasses-ionic4-android)

Answer (score 0):

This is a deprecated SDK.

We made some changes to Firebase ML Kit to better distinguish the on-device APIs from cloud based APIs. "[ML Kit](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/guides)"(without firebase branding) contains all the on-device APIs. [Here's](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/migration) the migration guide from firebase mlkit to mlkit. All further improvements and new APIs will be released only with the new ML Kit.