# Problem duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel found in modules

Tags: android, dependencies, build.gradle

I got these errors when I try to run the emulator

> Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy found in modules jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx-2.3.1-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1) and lifecycle-viewmodel-2.4.0-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.4.0)
>
> Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviderKt found in modules jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx-2.3.1-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1) and lifecycle-viewmodel-2.4.0-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.4.0)
>
> Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.ViewTreeViewModelKt found in modules jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx-2.3.1-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1) and lifecycle-viewmodel-2.4.0-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.4.0)

Note: This is not specific to the android emulator but problem with gradle build.

Comment: I am also facing this problem with gradle build. This is not specific to the android emulator

Comment: true, it is on all build you are right ! see my answer ;)

Answer (score 221):

Most likely, one of your dependencies uses the `kotlin` version of the `viewmodel` library whereas your code uses the `java` version.

**Specify both** to enforce the latest version for all dependencies:

```
def lifecycle_version = "2.4.0"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:$lifecycle_version"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
```

Comment: Thanks, I was not using viewmodel-ktx but looks like viewmodel-savedstate required it. So after adding viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version solved the issue.

Comment: Good one, this shall be marked as right answer. I have also a java module using lifecycle-viewmodel 2.4.0 and lifecycle-livedata 2.4.0, and the jetifier resistantly generate 2.3.1 and leads to conflict. Even I am not using ktx in java module after adding the lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.0 dependency, my error went a way.

Comment: Where do I put this in my project? Build.gradle?

Comment: @Jackie Yes, the app's `build.gradle` in the `dependencies` section.

Comment: Brilliant. Note for people on the latest kotlin (1.7.21, November 2022) that your `lifecycle_version` will be `2.5.1`. Other than that this solution still works.

Comment: Nice fix, I believe the source of error for me was when I was copying code into my project and I used the alt+enter to import the dependency and I guess I clicked the wrong option. So note to everyone be careful to import the correct dependency.

Answer (score 150):

I had the same problem and I solved it by adding only one line of code

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.0'
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked today. I have no idea which library uses classes. I added the following to solve the problem: implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.0'

Comment: I don't understand why people upvote this copycat answer. To begin with, this solution is incorrect and will break when the third-party library gets updated. You should specify **both** the kotlin and java versions. That way, you are in control of which `lifecycle-viewmodel` library version to use.

Comment: This works for me so I don't care whether it's a copycat answer or not, I've upvoted it. Saved me hours  after trying so many dependency resolution strategies

Comment: It worked for me. But still, I can't decide whether this answer is the proper solution.

Comment: adding implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1' works for me

Answer (score 47):

**PROBLEM**: I got this error when I updated the `appcompat` dependency to `1.5.1`.

**SOLUTION**: I updated the `appcompat` dependency to `1.6.1`. 
 *Later versions should also work.

```
// Pick one:
// Kotlin
implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
// Groovy
implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1"
```

**REASON**: This works because of a bug fix implemented in `1.6.0-beta01`.

The [1.6.0-beta01 release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/appcompat#1.6.0-beta01) state the following in the "Bug Fixes" section:

> `AppCompat` now explicitly depends on `Lifecycle` `2.5.1` and `SavedState` `1.2.0`. ([I7e3e2](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/2166606))

Comment: This is the best solution IMHO, because it elegantly fixes the underlying issue. The only downside is that it'using a release candidate instead of a stable version, but as soon as a stable version >=1.6.0 is released this won't be a problem anymore.

Comment: This solution worked for me. Very simple. I also used the 1.5.1 version and faced the error.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed the issue. Nowadays there is a newer alpha version androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.7.0-alpha01 This also fixes the issue.

Comment: Thanks, this works better for me, I just need to update to the latest stable version now which is 1.6.1 and the error went away

Comment: What a fix! Recently run into this after updating material dependency without update androidx.appcompat dependency. Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

I thought that eliminating duplicate classes is better than adding new ones, so I'll post my solution to this problem here:

```
configurations {
    all {
        exclude group: 'androidx.lifecycle', module: 'lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx'
    }
}
```

These lines of code need to be added to the project level build.gradle file - and the build error will go away along with the wasted memory (a bit, but still).

Strange and incomprehensible behavior. I got it after adding the Kotlin library to the project, which it was later decided to replace with a version for Java. If you go to the .gradle folder, you can find it there, but I'm not sure if removing it from there is a good idea, because it may be used in other libs. It is strange that gradle or AndroidStudio does not automatically solve this problem, because only dependencies for Java are specified in the build.gradle file.

Comment: What "memory" are you referring to? The PC or the Android device? From what I could see, there is no added bloat in the resulting APK (could be a result of `R8`).

Comment: I am talking about resulting apk

Comment: @l33t exactly - 12 870 436 bytes vs  13 102 070 bytes. As I already said - a bit, but still

Comment: I ran some tests. With all optimizations (e.g. Release + minify using R8), removing `lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx` reduces the size with **less than 1 kB**. Most likely `R8` is able to get rid of 99% of the bloat, leaving one or two extra classes (`classes.dex` differs). Your solution seems to work, but why doesn't the minifier get rid of those last classes? Could be a minor glitch in `R8` or perhaps there is a real third-party dependency that, at some point, needs these kotlin classes. Your numbers indicate some other problem.

Comment: @l33t I didn’t quite explain it correctly. To get the numbers that were mentioned, I excluded several libraries that I used explicitly, but were also present as dependencies in other libraries (but for example with lower versions). exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
        exclude group: 'androidx.lifecycle', module: 'lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx'
        exclude group: 'androidx.lifecycle', module: 'lifecycle-viewmodel:2.3.1'
        exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'commons-lang3' and others

Comment: Not helpful!!! ...

Answer (score 13):

for anyone using compose,
you just need to add

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.5.1"
```

Answer (score 9):

It helped me reverting appcompat from 1.5.0 to 1.4.2 as suggested in this thread: [Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy found in modules lifecycle-viewmodel-2.5.0-runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73406969/duplicate-class-androidx-lifecycle-viewmodellazy-found-in-modules-lifecycle-view)

Comment: I am not explicitly using any of those libraries and this is the only solution that helped me. The `configurations.all.exclude` did not work for me. Thanks!

Comment: Or upgrade appcompat to 1.6.0-rc1 (or higher), in 1.5.1 it was not fixed for me, even though the release notes state so.

Answer (score 8):

As directed by l33t, I added

```
def lifecycle_version = "2.5.1"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:$lifecycle_version"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
```

but put the lines in the wrong file and got

> Could not find method implementation() for arguments...

Solution: Make sure you're adding these dependencies in android/app/build.gradle, not android/build.gradle. [See here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45615474/gradle-error-could-not-find-method-implementation-for-arguments-com-android)

Comment: This solved my problem as of 15/05/2023 when trying to use the Web3Auth Plug n Play SDK in my Flutter app.

Answer (score 7):

I get the same error, any answers solved my issue. The key point is here to solve the error (preferences 1.2.0 in my project -> add exclude group).

```
  def preference_version = "1.2.0"
    implementation ("androidx.preference:preference:$preference_version"){
        exclude group: 'androidx.lifecycle', module:'lifecycle-viewmodel'
        exclude group: 'androidx.lifecycle', module:'lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx'
    }
```

Then use 2.5.1 version for lifecycle dependencies.

```
def lifecycle_version = "2.5.1"
// ViewModel
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:$lifecycle_version"
// LiveData
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:$lifecycle_version"
// Lifecycles only (without ViewModel or LiveData)
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:$lifecycle_version"

// https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:$lifecycle_version"
```

This is working fine, i hope that it will help some people !

Comment: To me, this is the right answer, but it still concerns me.  Not as much as how kotlin dependencies got pulled into a Java library.  :P

Answer (score 7):

While many of these answers will work, there is a better way to set transitive dependency versions rather than including the package as a direct dependency.

```
constraints {
   implementation('androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1') {
      because 'insert explanation here'
   }
}
```

Here's a breakdown https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_constraints.html

Comment: Very clean solution.

Comment: No other solution was working, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue and various of these solutions didn't work for me. Let me just post the set of dependencies that fixed the issue in my case:

```
ext {
        compose_version = "1.3.1"
        kotlin_version = "1.7.10"
        coroutines_version = "1.5.0"
        hilt_version= '2.44.2'
    }
...

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.5.1'
    implementation "androidx.compose.animation:animation:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.1.1'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutines_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$coroutines_version"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hilt_version"
    implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0'

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.5.3'
```

Answer (score 0):

VERSIONS OF "def lifecycle_version" IN ALL LINES MUST BE SAME

IN THIS CASE IS '2.5.1'

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1'

def lifecycle_version = '2.5.1'
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.5.1"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.5.1"
annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.5.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Experienced same version of the error;

```
   > Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy found in modules lifecycle-viewmodel-2.5.1-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.5.1) and lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx-2.2.0-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0)
```

My approach was to explicitly specify the version of **LiveData** to use, I do not use liveData anywhere in my project, but gradle needs to know what to use under the hood.

Add the below dependency to your problematic module - be sure to update the version to match what you use in your lifecycle dependencies.

```
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.0")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same errors and it turned out that I just forgot to close a curly brace } somewhere in my build.gradle file.

Answer (score -2):

After creating a new empty Compose activity, I got this error.
Update all dependencies to the latest version solve error with `Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy ...`