# Script 'C:\tools\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1070

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

This question looks similar to many other but the only change is "line: 1070". Many other line in other question.

I try many solutions: Remove the android folder, recreate it and the same happen. Reinstall flutter SDK, flutter clean etc... It happen when I switch to Flutter 2.8, but It happen also before, when I was in flutter master channel. I think it related to one of my dependencie

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\tools\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1070

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\tools\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 1m 3s
583 actionable tasks: 582 executed, 1 up-to-date
```

My dependencies

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.15.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  add_2_calendar: ^2.1.2
  auto_route: ^3.1.3
  awesome_notifications: ^0.6.19
  badges: ^2.0.2
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.0
  carousel_slider: ^4.0.0
  cloud_firestore: ^2.5.3
  cloud_functions: ^3.2.3
  connectivity_plus: ^2.1.0
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.4
  curved_navigation_bar: ^1.0.1
  equatable: ^2.0.3
  firebase_auth: ^3.3.3
  firebase_core: ^1.10.5
  firebase_analytics: ^9.0.3
  firebase_crashlytics: ^2.4.3
  firebase_dynamic_links: ^3.0.1
  firebase_messaging: ^11.2.3
  firebase_storage: ^10.2.3
  flare_flutter: ^3.0.2
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_card_swipper: ^0.4.0
  flutter_form_builder: ^7.0.0
  flutter_hooks: ^0.18.1
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_polyline_points: ^1.0.0
  flutter_slidable: ^1.1.0
  flutter_stripe: ^2.0.2
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.8
  font_awesome_flutter: '>= 4.7.0'
  form_builder_validators: ^7.2.0
  geoflutterfire2: ^2.3.10
  geolocator: ^8.0.0
  giphy_picker: ^2.0.0
  google_fonts: ^2.1.0
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.1.1
  google_maps_webservice: ^0.0.20-nullsafety.5
  google_sign_in: ^5.2.1
  hooks_riverpod: ^1.0.2
  http: ^0.13.4
  image_picker: ^0.8.4+4
  intl: ^0.17.0
  internet_connection_checker: ^0.0.1+3
  just_audio: ^0.9.18
  lint: ^1.7.2
  map_launcher: ^2.1.1
  multi_image_picker: ^4.8.1
  open_mail_app: ^0.4.1
  package_info_plus: ^1.3.0
  path_provider: ^2.0.8
  pdf: ^3.6.1
  permission_handler: ^8.3.0
  photo_view: ^0.13.0
  pixel_perfect: ^1.1.0
  printing: ^5.6.1
  qr_flutter: ^4.0.0
  rive: ^0.7.33
  rxdart: ^0.27.3
  share_plus: ^3.0.4
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.11
  shimmer: ^2.0.0
  swipe_to: 0.1.0-nullsafety.1
  url_launcher: ^6.0.17
  flutter_icons: ^1.1.0
  flutter_sound: ^8.4.2



dev_dependencies:
  auto_route_generator: ^3.1.0
  build_runner:
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.2
  flutter_native_splash: ^1.3.1
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^1.0.4
  json_annotation: ^4.3.0
```

Comment: I was right I was auto_route: ^3.2.0. I also need to upgrade android https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects and add this dependencies implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.0' get here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69817925/problem-duplicate-class-androidx-lifecycle-viewmodel-found-in-modules

Answer (score 2):

```
flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
```

This will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case "flutter upgrade" solved problem

Answer (score 0):

First of Fall check the flutter version is 2.8.1 then update by below code and check flutter versio is 3.3.4.

update the flutter: using command :" flutter upgrade "

check command is update is 3.3.4

then maybe you face this problem if your app
minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion if is set in flutter.gradle file in 16 or blow 16 then you go to this directory C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle and open flutter.gradle in noteped [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNgKm.png) .

changing static int minSdkVersion = 16 this to

static int minSdkVersion = 19

[!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin. │ │ Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html#plugin-and-versions, then │ │ update D:\Rohit\FLutter_LAB\example\android\build.gradle: │ │ ext.kotlin_version = ''

and to solve this go to the app\build.gradle :

defaultConfig { // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html). applicationId "com.example.example" minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion

```
    **multiDexEnabled true**  //ADD THIS LINE

versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
versionName flutterVersionName
```

}