# I got these error in my flutter code I've tried (flutter clean - flutter pub get - flutter upgrade - cache repair) all of it didn't work

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle

PS C:\Flutter\app\groceries-shopping-flutter-app> flutter run
Using hardware rendering with device AOSP on IA Emulator. If you notice graphics artifacts, consider
enabling software rendering with "--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib\main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_platform_widgets-0.72.0/lib/src/platform_app_bar.dart:202:9: Error: No named parameter with the name 'actionsForegroundColor'.
actionsForegroundColor: data?.actionsForegroundColor,
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/nav_bar.dart:245:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the
arguments don't match.
const CupertinoNavigationBar({
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_platform_widgets-0.72.0/lib/src/platform_app_bar.dart:222:7: Error: No named parameter with the name 'actionsForegroundColor'.
actionsForegroundColor: data?.actionsForegroundColor,
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/nav_bar.dart:245:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the
arguments don't match.
const CupertinoNavigationBar({
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.18.1/lib/src/picture_provider.dart:50:59: Error: No named parameter with the name 'nullOk'.
context != null ? Localizations.localeOf(context, nullOk: true) : null,
^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/localizations.dart:413:17: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
static Locale localeOf(BuildContext context) {
^^^^^^^^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1070
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\Flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 55s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             58.6s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Check this out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70319300/script-c-tools-flutter-packages-flutter-tools-gradle-flutter-gradle-line-107

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what the error means, you made a `CupertinoNavigationBar` and are passing into it an `actionsForegroundColor`, but doing that is not allowed as of version 1.22.

You can read more about it on [flutter 1.22 changes](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/1-22-deprecations#cupertino-navigation-bars-actionsforegroundcolor)

the new way to pass the equivalent parameter is by adding a `CupertinoTheme` somewhere above your `CupertinoNavigationBar` (I believe `CupertinoApp` does this automatically if you pass the theme parameter?) and passing a Cupertino theme data object with the primary color value.

```
CupertinoTheme(
  data: CupertinoThemeData(
    primaryColor: data?.actionsForegroundColor,
  ),
  child: CupertinoNavigationBar(),
);
```

or on `CupertinoApp`

```
CupertinoApp(
  theme: CupertinoThemeData(
    primaryColor: data?.actionsForegroundColor,
  ),
  home: ...
);
```