# Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy found in modules lifecycle-viewmodel-2.5.0-runtime

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, dependencies, build.gradle

I'm using **Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 2.**

I get the following error when I use the `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0'` version.

> Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy found in modules
> lifecycle-viewmodel-2.5.0-runtime
> (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.5.0) and
> lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx-2.3.1-runtime
> (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1) Duplicate class
> androidx.lifecycle.ViewTreeViewModelKt found in modules
> lifecycle-viewmodel-2.5.0-runtime
> (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.5.0) and
> lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx-2.3.1-runtime
> (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1)

It works fine after rolling back to the previous `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'` version.

`build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.halil.ozel.darkmode"
        minSdk 28
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'

    // Preference
    implementation "androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.2.0"
}
```

Can anyone help with similar error?

Thanks.

Comment: It is a duplicate question. I found answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/69832319/6825983

Comment: @Zeghra not really, this question is specific to the appCompat dependency, which introduces the issue. The other question is more generic, more for people who introduce the lifecycle dependencies themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, This problem was solved.

`build.gradle(project)`:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

`build.gradle(app)`:

```
...
android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.halil.ozel.catchthefruits"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
    }
}

...

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'

...
```

For more details:

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/appcompat

Comment: I'm still getting the same error with 1.5.1

Comment: I updated my solution. Can you check it? @Panther

Comment: implementation androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1

Comment: this worked for me already

Comment: It's fixed when upgrading appcompat to 1.6.0-rc1 (1.5.1 did not work for me).

Answer (score 26):

I had the same problem and I solved it by adding only one line of code

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.0'
```

Comment: Worked for me. Downgrading to 1.4.2 as suggested elsewhere didn't work for me. Thanks!

Comment: I had a similar issue in react native app solved by adding this dependency.

Answer (score 14):

I had this problem too. Apparently it's a bug specifically for version 1.5.0 having an explicit dependency on Lifecycle 2.3.1 and a transitive dependency on Lifecycle 2.5.0 via Activity 1.5.0.
It will be fixed with 1.5.1

Here is the issue tracker reference: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/242384116

Just roll back to 1.4.2 until it will be fixed.

Comment: For me it was not fixed for 1.5.1

Comment: I confirm that 1.5.1 didn't fix the issue...

Comment: It's fixed when upgrading appcompat to 1.6.0-rc1 (1.5.1 didn't work).

Answer (score 10):

In my case, solved by add this :

```
api "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1"
```

source : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/238425626

Comment: I don't use ViewModel in my project in useless why will I add library?

Comment: This seems to be a temporary solution.

Answer (score 6):

This works well for me

```
configurations {
    all {
      exclude group: 'androidx.lifecycle', module: 'lifecycle-runtime-ktx'
      exclude group: 'androidx.lifecycle', module: 'lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx'
    }
  }
```

Comment: please clear to me  add it in android{} block or dependencies{} block

Comment: inside android{} block :D

Comment: Module-level `build.gradle` file, inside the `android{}` block.

Answer (score 3):

This bug is **fixed in AppCompat 1.6.0**.
(and if you need androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx, use 2.5.1 or above)

```
implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.0"
```

The issue description is here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/242384116.

Issue description excerpt:

> This was caused by AppCompat 1.5.0 having an explicit dependency on
> Lifecycle 2.3.1 and a transitive dependency on Lifecycle 2.5.0 via
> Activity 1.5.0.
>
> Since AppCompat 1.6.0-beta01, it now depends explicitly on Lifecycle 2.5.1 so this is no longer an issue. We can backport these
> bumps into an AppCompat 1.5.1 as well.

*Note:

Using kotlin version '1.7.20'*

Answer (score 1):

I have also this implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0' version

In my case, solved by doing this

First I updated it to version implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.0'

Also updated targetSdk and minSdk version to 33

Comment: There is already an answer recommending to not use 1.5.0

Answer (score 0):

This works for me ->

```
kotlin_version = '1.7.22
appcompat_version = "1.6.0-beta01"
lifecycle_version = "2.5.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

This work perfectly for me.

**File:** `android/app/build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
{/* Add in last */}
     implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.0-beta01'
     implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1'
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?