# Android Studio Chipmunk duplicate class error

Tags: android, gradle

I am getting the following error when Gradle is set 7.2.2.
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy found in modules jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx-2.3.1-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1) and lifecycle-viewmodel-2.5.1-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.5.1)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.ViewTreeViewModelKt found in modules jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx-2.3.1-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1) and lifecycle-viewmodel-2.5.1-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.5.1)

This is not in my program but in Android Studio.

How do I correct the problem?

Thanks,
Bill

Comment: Write code in code box.

Comment: Which code? There is no `build.gradle` at all.

Comment: There is a build.gradle. Will not fit in this space.

Comment: Could this be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69817925 ?

Answer (score 0):

In your build.gradle try adding this:

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.5.1"
```

This worked for me.

I added it but no change.

```
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy found in modules jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx-2.3.1-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1) and lifecycle-viewmodel-2.5.1-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.5.1)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.ViewTreeViewModelKt found in modules jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx-2.3.1-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1) and lifecycle-viewmodel-2.5.1-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.5.1)
```

Answer (score -1):

This error is caused by **duplication of dependencies**

To solve the same:

1. You must open **Gradle Scripts-->build.gradle**(Module: YourApp)

Or

2. You can just choose to search the builder:app file in **Navigate--> Search Everywhere**, type "*build.gradle* " and choose the option that appears build.gradle (: app)

Inside your build.gradle file it checks which of the implementations made in the dependencies tag was duplicated and deletes one of them.
Now

> rebuild your app and good work!