# Android KTX conflict with java version

Tags: java, android, kotlin, build.gradle, androidx

I have a project that need 2 libraries. one of the library have a dependency to `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1` and the other have a dependency to `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.5.1`. How this must be resolved ? When I try to compile the project I receive

> Error: E7688 Type androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy is defined multiple
> times:
> androidx.lifecycle-lifecycle-viewmodel-2.5.1-dexed.jar:classes.dex,
> androidx.lifecycle-lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx-2.3.1-dexed.jar:classes.dex

Comment: Use the same version for both (2.5.1). See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69817925/6808319).