# How to find android dependencies from all flutter plugins

Tags: flutter, android-gradle-plugin, flutter-dependencies, google-play-core

I am trying to implement flutter plugin [in_app_review](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_review) in one of my flutter project but i am getting duplicate dependency error.
I think some of the plugin from my project is somewhere adding play core dependency which is causing this issue.
Please help me figure out the solution.

I am getting this error log.

Execution failed for task ':app:checkUatDebugDuplicateClasses'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
> Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.common.IntentSenderForResultStarter found in modules jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0) and jetified-core-common-2.0.2-runtime (com.google.android.play:core-common:2.0.2)
> Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.common.LocalTestingException found in modules jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0) and jetified-core-common-2.0.2-runtime (com.google.android.play:core-common:2.0.2)
> Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.common.PlayCoreDialogWrapperActivity found in modules jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0) and jetified-core-common-2.0.2-runtime (com.google.android.play:core-common:2.0.2)
> Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.listener.StateUpdatedListener found in modules jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0) and jetified-core-common-2.0.2-runtime (com.google.android.play:core-common:2.0.2)
> Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.review.ReviewInfo found in modules jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0) and jetified-review-2.0.1-runtime (com.google.android.play:review:2.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.review.ReviewManager found in modules jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0) and jetified-review-2.0.1-runtime (com.google.android.play:review:2.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.review.ReviewManagerFactory found in modules jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0) and jetified-review-2.0.1-runtime (com.google.android.play:review:2.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.review.testing.FakeReviewManager found in modules jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0) and jetified-review-2.0.1-runtime (com.google.android.play:review:2.0.1)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56716047/execution-failed-for-task-appcheckdebugduplicateclasses-ionic4-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem. It was happening because I was using;

`implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3'`

`implementation'com.google.android.play:core-ktx:1.8.1'`

These two dependencies are in my android folder for in-app update and I thought `com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3` is responsible for the duplicate dependency issue so when I commented that out it was still giving duplicate dependency issue as `com.google.android.play:core-ktx:1.8.1` is also the same so I check on [developer guide page](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore) where this dependency is now separated according to feature from core dependency then I removed this two dependencies and added implementation `'com.google.android.play:app-update-ktx:2.0.1'` this one as I was doing the in-app update as well.
which helped me fix my problem.

Answer (score 2):

my app has both in_app_review and rate_my_app and i have the same issue.
i solved it by locking in_app_review to 2.0.4:
2.0.4 not ^2.0.4.

looks like 2.0.5 introduced this bug.

Comment: For now I also had to set `rate_my_app: "1.1.3"` rather than ^1.1.3 - at least until I have time to investigate further as the latest `1.1.4` also seems to introduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me it removing the rate_my_app package fixed it