# Simple Cordova app with just Firebase plugin doesn't build or run on Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, cordova, cordova-plugins

I made a very simple Cordova project, added the Android platform and the Firebase plugin. I can't get it to build or run. I get errors after errors.

Here are the steps:

1. cordova create hello com.example.hello Hello
2. cordova platform add android
3. cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase

Or, just download the code from: https://github.com/abelabbesnabi/cordova.git

I have the following environment:

1. Cordova 9.0.0
2. Android Studio 3.5
   Build #AI-191.8026.42.35.5791312, built on August 8, 2019
   JRE: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03 amd64
   JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
3. Windows 10 10.0

Any idea please?

Comment: did u click ok?

Comment: @PeterHaddad That was not the issue. I just said that so people click on "Ok" to move forward and not get stuck there. Anyways, I removed that screenshot so people don't get confused :)

Answer (score 0):

change 
`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase` with

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebasex
```

another option is after adding cordova-plugin-firebase add 2 another plugin

[cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release)

[cordova-android-firebase-gradle-release](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-firebase-gradle-release)

Comment: It doesn't work, unfortunately. I'm getting these errors: 
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1) and many more duplicate errors...

Comment: Did you try changing gradle.properties file https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55909804/duplicate-class-android-support-v4-app-inotificationsidechannel-found-in-modules/55932544

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to make it work:

1. cordova platform remove android
2. cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-firebase
3. cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase-lib
4. cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx
5. cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter

That's it!