# Android Studio 3.5: not able to resolve LocalBroadcastManager

Tags: android, localbroadcastmanager

We are trying implement LocalBroadcastManager in our Android app but facing "Cannot resolve" error.

This is the object we need -
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager

### Included the library in app build.gradle (as stated in that page)

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:localbroadcastmanager:28.0.0'
```

### Included Maven in Solution `build.gradle`

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

Gradle version is 5.4.1
```

Below line throws "Cannot resolve symbol" error

```
LocalBroadcastManager localBroadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context);
```

Please let me know what we might be missing. Appreciate your help.

Comment: No we haven't. Do you recommend that we enable Jetifier and use Androidx as listed by "nice j" ? We haven't used Androidx so far, will it cause any compatibility issue with rest of libraries ?

Answer (score 2):

I checked it in Android Studio 3.5 and I didn't see any problem. but I use androidX and `LocalBroadcastManager` imported from
 `androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager;`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you recommend that we enable Jetifier and use Androidx as listed by "nice j" ? We haven't used Androidx so far, will it cause any compatibility issue with rest of libraries ?

Comment: @KrishnanVS definitely I recommend it because Google is stopping support for com.android.support and you need to migrate.. I didn't have problem in my migrate but don't forget this https://stackoverflow.com/a/55932544/5282127

Comment: Great, thank you for the help. We will check this out right away and update the response.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you enabled Jetifier therefore you shouldn't use support dependencies:

Replace

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0' 
implementation 'com.android.support:localbroadcastmanager:28.0.0'
```

with

```
implementation 'androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0'
```

Here's documentation for it:
https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/localbroadcastmanager/content/LocalBroadcastManager

Comment: Thank you for your reply, will check this right away.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the suggestions, migrating to androidx worked. We are getting the broadcast call to Receiver now. Appreciate the prompt help very much.