# Android Studio Bumblebee android.arch.lifecycle:extensions implementation

Tags: android, kotlin, build.gradle, android-architecture-navigation, android-studio-bumblebee

i updated android studio and build.gradle changed.
In old versions, I was able to add like:

```
dependencies {
def lifeCycleExtensionVersion = '1.1.1'    
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$lifeCycleExtensionVersion"}
```

But now i am getting error how can i add

Comment: can you share what error are you getting?

Comment: Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub found in modules core-1.7.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.7.0) and support-compat-26.1.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)

Comment: You can add below 2 lines into your gradle.properties file:

android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting different error not as you mentioned in question please follow this URL

[duplicate-class-android-support-v4-app-inotificationsidechannel-found-in-modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55909804/duplicate-class-android-support-v4-app-inotificationsidechannel-found-in-modules)

Comment: I added Android.enableJetifier=true in gradle.properties and my problem was solved thank you for your support.