# Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$Action$Extender found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I'm getting multiple lines of errors saying that it has duplicate class

> Duplicate class
>
> android.support.v4.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat
>   found in modules classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0) and classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0) 
>   Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle found in modules
>   classes.jar (com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0) and
>   classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0) 
>   Duplicate class
>   Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution
>   errors.

My `gradle.app` has dependencies as below:

```
dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find dependencies causing class duplication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55965550/how-do-i-find-dependencies-causing-class-duplication)

Answer (score 1):

You need to upgrade the version, you can do this by using the sequence <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> over the line:

[image]

Nowadays you don´t need to use all Google Play Services, just modules, examples:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:VERSION'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:VERSION'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:VERSION'
```

but if you really need to use `'com.google.android.gms:play-services:VERSION'`, to avoid duplicated classes uses this configuration inside your `app/build.gradle` file:

```
implementation ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.4') {
    exclude group: "com.android.support", module: "support-v4"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**thanks the above  answer by Jorgesys is correct  but i  migrate to androidx which solved my problem**

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

// paste this properties in gradle.properties

android.useAndroidX=true

android.enableJetifier=true

1. First Property will use appropriate androidx libraries instead of using old support libraries.
2. Second will migrate all third party libraries to androidx libraries.