# Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle found in modules classe

Tags: java, android, maven

This is not a Duplicate of [Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$Action$Extender found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56402573/duplicate-class-android-support-v4-app-notificationcompatactionextender-found) issue because we don't used `com.google.android.gms:play-services` 
and the soluction provided buy them is to update google play libary

When we add this repositories {

```
    maven {
        url "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/elasticode-sdk/Android/maven/"
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.elasticode.sdk:elasticode-android:2.1.1'
}
```

> build gradel

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }


    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

> my module app file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/elasticode-sdk/Android/maven/"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.elasticode.sdk:elasticode-android:2.1.1'


}
```

it making error

> Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat
>   found in modules classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0) and classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle found in modules
>   classes.jar (com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0) and
>   classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle$Delegate found in modules
>   classes.jar (com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0) and
>   classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle$DelegateProvider found in
>   modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0) and
>   classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle$SlideDrawable found in
>   modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0) and
>   classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat found in modules classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0) and classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat$1 found in modules classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0) and classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat$OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback
>   found in modules classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0) and classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat$SharedElementCallback21Impl
>   found in modules classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0) and classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.app.ActivityManagerCompat found in modules
>   classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0) and
>   classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.app.ActivityOptionsCompat found in modules
>   classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0) and
>   classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.app.AppOpsManagerCompat found in modules
>   classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0) and
>   classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord found in modules classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0) and classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord$Op found in modules classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0) and classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackState found in modules classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0) and classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackState$1 found in modules classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0) and classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment found in modules classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0) and classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment found in modules classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0) and classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment$1 found in modules classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0) and classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException found in
>   modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0) and
>   classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment$SavedState found in modules
>   classes.jar (com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0) and
>   classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment$SavedState$1 found in modules
>   classes.jar (com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0) and
>   classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity found in modules classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0) and classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$1 found in modules classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0) and classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks found in modules
>   classes.jar (com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0) and
>   classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$NonConfigurationInstances
>   found in modules classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0) and classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentContainer found in modules classes.jar
>
> modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0) and
>   internal_impl-23.0.0.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0)
>   Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory
>   found in modules classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0) and classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory$DefaultRoundedBitmapDrawable
>   found in modules classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0) and classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.hardware.display.DisplayManagerCompat found in
>   modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0) and
>   classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManagerCompat found
>   in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0) and
>   classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManagerCompat$AuthenticationCallback found in modules classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0) and classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) Duplicate class
>
> (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.widget.ScrollerCompat found in modules classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0) and classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter found in modules
>   classes.jar (com.android.support:cursoradapter:28.0.0) and classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter$CursorToStringConverter
>   found in modules classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:cursoradapter:28.0.0) and classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter$ViewBinder found in
>   modules classes.jar (com.android.support:cursoradapter:28.0.0) and
>   classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout found in modules
>   classes.jar (com.android.support:slidingpanelayout:28.0.0) and
>   classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout$AccessibilityDelegate
>   found in modules classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:slidingpanelayout:28.0.0) and classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout$DisableLayerRunnable found
>   in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:slidingpanelayout:28.0.0)
>   and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) Duplicate
>   class android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout$DragHelperCallback
>   found in modules classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:slidingpanelayout:28.0.0) and classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout$LayoutParams found in
>   modules classes.jar (com.android.support:slidingpanelayout:28.0.0) and
>   classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout$PanelSlideListener found
>   in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:slidingpanelayout:28.0.0)
>   and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) Duplicate
>   class android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout$SavedState found in
>   modules classes.jar (com.android.support:slidingpanelayout:28.0.0) and
>   classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout$SavedState$1 found in
>   modules classes.jar (com.android.support:slidingpanelayout:28.0.0) and
>   classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout$SimplePanelSlideListener
>   found in modules classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:slidingpanelayout:28.0.0) and classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.widget.Space found in modules classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0) and classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout found in modules
>   classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) and classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:swiperefreshlayout:28.0.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout$1 found in modules
>   classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) and classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:swiperefreshlayout:28.0.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout$2 found in modules
>   classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) and classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:swiperefreshlayout:28.0.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout$3 found in modules
>   classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) and classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:swiperefreshlayout:28.0.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout$4 found in modules
>   classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) and classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:swiperefreshlayout:28.0.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout$5 found in modules
>   classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) and classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:swiperefreshlayout:28.0.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout$6 found in modules
>   classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) and classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:swiperefreshlayout:28.0.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout$7 found in modules
>   classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) and classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:swiperefreshlayout:28.0.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout$8 found in modules
>   classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) and classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:swiperefreshlayout:28.0.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout$OnRefreshListener found
>   in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) and
>   classes.jar (com.android.support:swiperefreshlayout:28.0.0) Duplicate
>   class android.support.v4.widget.TextViewCompat found in modules
>   classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0) and
>   classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.widget.TintableCompoundButton found in modules
>   classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0) and
>   internal_impl-23.0.0.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0)
>   Duplicate class android.support.v4.widget.ViewDragHelper found in
>   modules classes.jar (com.android.support:customview:28.0.0) and
>   classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.widget.ViewDragHelper$1 found in modules
>   classes.jar (com.android.support:customview:28.0.0) and classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.widget.ViewDragHelper$2 found in modules
>   classes.jar (com.android.support:customview:28.0.0) and classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0) Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.widget.ViewDragHelper$Callback found in modules
>   classes.jar (com.android.support:customview:28.0.0) and classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$Action$Extender found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56402573/duplicate-class-android-support-v4-app-notificationcompatactionextender-found)